# angular-ivh-treeview show only selected nodes and disabled checkbox

Tags: angularjs, treeview, directive

Searched the internet a long time but didn't find a way to do the following:

Show only selected nodes and make the checkbox disabled.

Looked to use a filter (ivh-treeview-filter) to show only nodes which are selected, but providing a filter function does not work (ivh-treeview mentions it uses Angular filterFilter. Any examples around to use a filter function?

There is a ivh-treeview-visible-attribute in ivh-treeview.js, however i think there is no active code for this, anywhere an example where this works?

How can i make the checkboxes disabled?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please add some code and more information to help us understand what your problem is.

Comment: ivh-Tree does not offer this functionality. You will need to understand the directive and do the change in that code. I suggest, do not do that as it is fairly big directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, ivh-treeview provides a jsbin template in its README for demos, perhaps you could show us what you've attempted so far? I'll take a stab though.

You can definitely use `ivh-treeview-filter` to show only selected nodes. Define a function like so in your controller:

```
this.mySweetFilter = function(node) {
  return node.selected;
};
```

And pass it to your directive:

```
<div ivh-treeview="vm.treeData"
     ivh-treeview-filter="vm.mySweetFilter">
</div>
```

Here's a fully working demo that lets you toggle whether all nodes are visible or just the selected ones: http://jsbin.com/nirovahupa/1/edit?html,js,output.

As for disabling checkboxes dynamically - there's nothing baked in to the directive to allow you to do this. You can however (and are encouraged to) use your own custom node templates and it would be a simple matter of hiding the treeview checkboxes and showing your own disabled ones as needed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx for showing the filter as a function works. We made our own directive with a template as yours; have to check once again if we made a mistake.

Comment: We changed the code also for disabling the checkbox and wrapped it on our own directive. We changed the template in ivh-treeview-checkbox-helper.js. Could you please show how to override the checkbox template. One thing we still have to figure out is, that a parent toggle (not disabled node), changes the child checkbox value for a disabled checkbox node. Will have to look into the callback functions today.

Comment: This demo - http://jsbin.com/jaqosi/edit?html,js,output - replaces the build in checkboxes with custom ones. You could imagine instead having disabled checkboxes in addition with to the normal ones but only show one set at a time depending on your toggle state. Even simpler, you could also just have your toggle find and disable/enable all checkboxes in the tree when clicked.

Comment: Thx Russell, got the filter using a function fixed and got a better insight of using templates. Would be great to see an example page on your github home page to the many jsbin's you made.

Comment: Is there any way to get the only the selected nodes with its tree structure to a variable? http://jsbin.com/nirovahupa/1/edit?html,js,output. this one is perfect as I have expected but I need it in a variable as a json.